# Problema con barra de scrollbar en un Canvas, aparece fuera del mismo

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Estoy intentando crear un `Canvas` con una `ScrollBar` para poder cargar una imagen y manipularla. Tengo el siguiente código:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import Tk    
from tkinter import PhotoImage
from tkinter import Canvas
from tkinter import NW
from tkinter import Menu
from tkinter import filedialog
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from sys import argv
import tkinter as tk

ventana =Tk ()

ventana.geometry("900x900+0+0")
ventana.title("PRUEBA 1")
ventana.config(bg="#cdc9c9")

canvas = Canvas (ventana, height=400, width=600,bg='#faf0e6') 

scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(ventana, command=canvas.yview)
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill='y')
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
canvas.pack()

ventana.mainloop()
```

El problema está en que la barra de scroll no queda dentro del canvas, sino que queda posicionada en el borde de la ventana.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lógicamente la `ScrollBar` aparece en su widget padre, en este caso `ventana`. No puedes posicionar una `ScrollBar` en el canvas directamente, lo que si puedes hacer es usar un `Frame` extra como contenedor y que agrupe el canvas y la `ScrollBar`.

Hay que tener en cuenta una característica especial de `Canvas`, **el espacio de coordenadas del lienzo no tiene límites**, en cada momento solo está visible una fracción muy pequeña del espacio de coordenadas disponible.

Para solucionar esto, basta con limitar el desplazamiento a un área determinada mediante `config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height)`, en este caso el tamaño de la imagen).

```
from sys import argv
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog


ventana = tk.Tk ()

ventana.geometry("900x900+0+0")
ventana.title("PRUEBA 1")
ventana.config(bg="#cdc9c9")

img_frame = tk.Frame(ventana, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6')
img_frame.pack()
canvas = tk.Canvas (img_frame, height=400, width=600, bg='#faf0e6', relief=tk.SUNKEN)

sbarV = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
sbarH = tk.Scrollbar(img_frame, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
sbarV.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
sbarH.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)

canvas.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
canvas.pack(side=tk.LEFT, expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)


img_path =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Select file",
                                       filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),
                                       ("all files","*.*")))
img = Image.open(img_path)
width, height = img.size
canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, width, height))
img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
imagesprite = canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor="nw", image=img2)


ventana.mainloop()
```

Esto nos muestra la imagen dentro de nuestro `Canvas` con dos `ScrollBars` para poder desplazarnos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]